# Find file in a project in a mono-repo like `projectile-find-file`

Tags: projectile

My code base consists of a "mono-repo". A single large repository containing a flat structure of projects.

```
Top
  Project1
  Project2
  Project3
  Library
  Library
```

I've been using Projectile to navigate this so far, but I'm starting to get to the point where I want to be able to search within a given library or project. I have a function that will return the root of a library or project.

How can I use `projectile-find-file`, or something like it, within one of these projects?

## Work so far

I found the following command `(helm-find-1 (my-mono-find-root))` that does something close to what I want. I'd quite like it to ignore some files tho.

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/920psp/projectile_ignoring_projectile_files/.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear.  Are you looking for faster navigation or faster location of items below Top?  Do those projects need to be loaded, such as activating a Python virtual environment?

Comment: @LoremIpsum Thanks for the reply Lorem, I want to be able to search files within `Project1`. I want a separate command to search `Top`.

Answer (score 1):

To look within a particular project, I often use [`ag`](https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el).   It is a front end for [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) which allows you to recursively search a directory for a regexp in a file or filename.  The `ag` package presents a nice list of matches with links to their source.  Similar packages exist for [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) ([`(emacs) Grep Searching`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) or via `C-h i d m emacs <RET> m Grep Searching`) and [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) ([`rg.el`](https://github.com/dajva/rg.el)).

Comment: So I'm interested in search *filenames* here (though I'm also interested in searching the content of files).

Comment: `rg.el` for ripgrep. https://github.com/dajva/rg.el

Comment: @AttRigh  Sorry, I linked `ag-files` previously which was incorrect.  That searches *within* files.  To search filenames, use `ag-dired`: https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el/blob/master/ag.el#L519